# How to scan integer values from a file separated by colon

Tags: c

I am trying to get the integers values to be passed to a `linked list` from a text file.

The problem is that the text file is structured as columns and rows.

This is an example below regarding the text file:

```
5:0:3
4:1:2
3:1:1
4:2:2
3:3:1
```

How can I get these values? Noting that my program should notice the `:` and not only the `EOF`. I wrote a similar program but it can't take care of the colon. it only scans the integer values until the `EOF`.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, how much you understand c++, otherwise this question is "to broad", since we do not know what knowledge you have of c++, IDE ecc.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Concentrate on one of them!

Comment: I am okay with C and C++. Working with classes, data structures and writing some OS tasks...

Comment: I have removed the C++ tag based on your description. If that's not correct, tag it back.

Comment: This is okay! I've added the C++ tag since this one can be solved using both of them, without implementing the C++ one in an object oriented form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) to read lines and then [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) to parse each line. If the lines, contain only 3 integers then it can be done as:

```
int i, j, k;
char str[256];
FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "r");

if(!fp) {
   /* File opening error */
}

while(fgets(str, sizeof str, fp)) {
   char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
   if (p) *p = 0; // remove the trailing newline, if 

   if( sscanf(str, "%d:%d:%d", &i, &j, &k) == 3) {
      printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);
      /* do processing with i, j & k */
   }
   else {
      /* failure */
   }
}
```

Comment: This is so useful! Thank you very much

Comment: Clear and simple, but could be made simpler: stripping the `'\n'` is not really necessary.

Comment: I added it out of habit. I though it's something OP needs to be aware of even if it's unnecessary in this use-case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fscanf` as

```
fscanf(fp, "%d:%d:%d", &var1, &var2, &var3);
```

Comment: I've got the trick, the usage of "%d:" is solving it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the entire line as a string using getline.

Then you can use the string function `find()` to find the :

After that you'll have saved in what position in the string the : was found, and you can convert the character that is one position behind the : into a integer using atoi(). That works for the first 2 numbers.

For the last number, you do the same thing but instead of : you look for a space.

Comment: @iharob To be fair, OP originally had both C and C++ tags. It's me who removed C++ tag based on OP's comments and description.

Comment: @I3x thank you for the information, it was unfair to downvote then.